# How can I perfect the logic of lock-screen?

Tags: javascript, lockscreen

When you need to temporarily leave your web application and computer unattended, there’s a safe way to put it to screen-lock status and unlock it by input your unique password again. Shows our login screen without logging you out in our web applications seems easy to add a lock screen page like this.

Lock screen Demo from Metronic

[image]

But how can I perfect the logic of lock-screen.
For example can i let the other people can not use the forward or backward tools change the current url?

Comment: Run a `setTImeout` inside of `mousemove`. Just have it `clearTimeout` and reset every time the mouse moves.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the login part of it, since you should use AJAX to send to the Server and Login over SSL:

```js
// external.js
var doc, bod, htm, C, E, T; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){

doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
T = function(tag){
  return doc.getElementByTagName(tag);
}
var form = E('form'), fS = form.style, sub = E('sub'), tO;
function tF(){
  // code within this func inside logout ajax
  fS.display = 'block';
}
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
});
sub.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // run code within this func inside login ajax
  fS.display = 'none'; E('un').value = E('pw').value = '';
  tO = setTimeout(tF, 10000);
  addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    if(tO)clearTimeout(tO);
    tO = setTimeout(tF, 10000);
  });
});
form.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev){
  if(ev.keyCode === 13)sub.click();
});

});
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  background:#000; padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; background:#fff; margin:0 auto;
}
#form{
  width:250px; background:green; padding:10px;
}
#form>label,#form>input{
  display:block;
}
#form>label{
  float:left; width:100px; color:#fff;
}
#form>input{
  width:140px; margin-bottom:10px;
}
#form>#sub{
  width:70px; height:30px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Lockout</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='form'>
        <label for='un'>USERNAME</label><input id='un' name='un' type='text' value='' /> 
      <label for='pw'>PASSWORD</label><input id='pw' name='pw' type='password' value='' />
      <input id='sub' type='button' value='LOGIN' />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code shows how to achieve this using a 10 second timer.

Answer (score -1):

By definition, you can't.

The backwards and forwards buttons are browser's capability so there's no way you can alter it with Javascript.

What you can do though is whenever a user is locked there's no way for him to leave the lock page (if locked every page redirect to lock page)

Comment: Yes you are right. Can you tell me how make people no way to leave the lock page (if locked every page redirect to lock page).

Comment: I use event listent **onbeforeunload**  but the page can't lock. Can you give me a hint?   `window.onbeforeunload=function (){ // }`